# Generating strings from context free grammars

Tags: algorithm, context-free-grammar

The problem is implementing an algorithm, that generates all strings with length between **l** and **r** from given context free grammar **G**.

I have come up with simple approach: run BFS on grammar graph, remembering states.
But it fails on some recursive rules:

```
(1)   S -> 0 | SSS | λ
```

I can't simply limit maximum string length, because rules can contain λ (empty strings), so non-terminals can reduce final string length. (eg. running (1) with `l = 1`,  `r = 2` will output only 0 in my implementation)

I also tried to limit maximum number of applied rules, but it is obviously wrong too.

How i can limit or change my algorithm, so it will never go in endless loop and will work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the grammer to [Greibach normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form), and then each step<sup>1</sup>  in the creationis increasing the size of the produced word, and you will be able to limit the length of the word as initially explained in the question.

---

(1) except possibly the first, if the empty word is in the grammer